# asp.net core project with a status of unloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an APS.NET project that suddenly shows unloaded and cannot look into the file.

May I know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Right click and "load project" or something similar. If it fails to load then double check the output window for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project and select Reload project.

[image: See picture here]